# create a table with avg() from other table that updates automatically like a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a "rating" table with multiple columns like the one bellow

**user_id   subject_id   subject_rating**

```
1           25             9
2           20             6
1           20             8
3           25             10
```

I want to create another table "av_rating" with a column that stores average rating from the column "subject_rating" found in the "rating" table above. I have tried the following code

```
CREATE TABLE av_rating AS SELECT AVG(subject_rating) FROM rating WHERE subject_id=25
```

the problem with this code is that it does not update the value in the new table after the initial value is stored even if the values in the first "rating" table is changed. I tried using the FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE with av() but couldn't get the syntax right.

Thank you and I am sorry if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the scale of data you are dealing with, you will probably want to create either a view or a materialized view (which don't exist natively in MySQL but can be approximated). For a small dataset (lets say less than a 100k rows) or if the performance of the query isn't a major concern, I suspect a view should suffice.

Typically one wouldn't include such a specific `WHERE` clause in the definition of a view or materialized view. Instead, you probably want to select the average subject_value within each subject and then join to those values based on the subject_id.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW av_rating AS
SELECT subject_id, AVG(subject_rating) avg
  FROM rating
 GROUP by subject_id
;
```

Which in the example case would generate the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM av_rating
;

---------------------------------
 subject_id |        avg
------------+--------------------
         25 | 9.5000000000000000
         20 | 7.0000000000000000
```